# Update a single row without any identification column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a very peculiar problem, consider these two rows:

```
val   | text     | akr       | usr_bk      
-----------------------------------------------
001   | hello    | 1024      | admin
001   | hello    | 1024      | admin
```

As you see, I have no unique columns or other identificators.

But; Is it possible (and how) to update just **one** row to have, e.g. `val = 002` **without** modifying the other row?

I'm running on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9862688/1618257 (though instead of DELETE you can use UPDATE and an incrementing variable if necessary)

Comment: @MattBusche Look at the answer by spender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to know which one you want, but you can do it like this with the example data you gave:

```
;WITH NumberedTbl AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY val, text, akr, admin
    ORDER BY val, text, akr, admin
  ) AS RowNumber,
  val, text, akr, admin
  FROM tbl
)

UPDATE t
SET val = '002'
FROM NumberedTbl t
WHERE t.RowNumber = 1

SELECT * FROM tbl
```

see this [SqlFiddle for a live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4506e/4/0). What you're probably going to want to do is build this and set it up so that you filter the `WITH` table like this:

```
;WITH NumberedTbl AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY val, text, akr, admin
    ORDER BY val, text, akr, admin
  ) AS RowNumber,
  val, text, akr, admin
  FROM tbl
  WHERE ... -- ADD SOME WHERE CLAUSE HERE
)
```